ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users.routing.websocket_urlpatterns'; 'users.routing' is not a package
I am tring to setup realtime connection between User Dashboard and Admin Dashboard for Notifications.
This is my backend/asgi.py
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from users.routing import websocket_urlpatterns

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'backend.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})

backend/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/users/', include('users.urls')),
    re_path(r'^ws/', include('users.routing.websocket_urlpatterns')),
]

users/routing.py
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/notifications/', consumers.NotificationConsumer.as_asgi()),
]

users/consumers.py
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class NotificationConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.group_name = 'notifications'

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        message = data['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.group_name,
            {
                'type': 'notification_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    async def notification_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))

When I Test importing in Django Shell it works
(venv) lucy@lucy:~/staking_platform$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 22 2023, 10:22:35) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from users.routing import websocket_urlpatterns
>>> 
now exiting InteractiveConsole...

But if I try to run qcluster it shows ModuleNotFoundError
(venv) lucy@lucy:~/staking_platform$ python manage.py qcluster Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()   File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 453, in execute
    self.check()   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/backend/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    re_path(r'^ws/', include('users.routing.websocket_urlpatterns')),   File "/home/lucy/staking_platform/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 970, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users.routing.websocket_urlpatterns'; 'users.routing' is not a package

I am lost looking for someone to help me out.

better put error message again - and keep original formatting.
